# WebMatrix UrlData collection not getting filled in MVC

Tags: model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-3, webmatrix

I have an MVC 3 application which employs WebMatrix in one of its pages.

I have something like this in the page:

```
string s1 = UrlData[0];
var query = "select * from test where id = " + UrlData[1];
// Open the database of the service delivery
var dataBase = Database.Open("connection_string");
var results = database.Query(query);
```

There is an MVC Dropdownlist in the page and in the onchange event of this dropdownlist i am submitting the MVC form. It goes to the controller method which has this dropdownlist value as the parameter and after some operations is redirected back to the same page using RedirectToAction().

But, the UrlData collection does not have any values. Could some one help me out with this?

Thanks
Nidhin

Comment: What do you mean by "employs WebMatrix" in one of its pages?

Answer (score 1):

UrlData is sorta like a Querystring with the execption that each value is located by position not by name. So if you where to have  Url like  http://localhost:6324/A/B/C/D in you Default.cshtml page and you did the following code:

```
<p>Total number of items in UrlData: @UrlData.Count</p>
<ul>
    @for(var i = 0; i < UrlData.Count; i++){
        <li>UrlData[@i]: @UrlData[i]</li>
    }
</ul>
```

the output would look like

```
    UrlData[0] : A
    UrlData[1] : B
    UrlData[2] : C
    UrlData[3] : D
```

To clarify even further here is a "fantastic" article on the subject
[UrlData](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/165/WebMatrix-URLs-UrlData-and-Routing-for-SEO)

Comment: "Nice" article? It's fantastic! ;o)